# Joining multiple tables returning 0 for specific column? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I'm having a problem at the moment where I have a column called `rating` in the `links` table and there is definitely values other than `0` within the column but `0` is the only value which is returned foreach link. When I do a simple get for that column it then shows all the other values but not when I do an SQL Join.

I know the problem is my joining of the tables but I'm unsure how I would go about joining these specific tables.

Database Table Structure

The `rating` column is the one which is causing me problems.

`'links'` `id | title | url | user_id | list_id | rating | weight | date_created`

`'list'` `id | list_title | list_description | user_id | rating | views | date_created`

`'link_ratings'` `id | user_id | link_id | rated | date_created`

Model:

```
public function get_latest(){

    $this->db->limit(100);
    $this->db->order_by('links.date_created', 'DESC');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select('links.id as current_link_id');
    $this->db->from('links');
    $this->db->join('list', 'links.list_id = list.id'); 
    $this->db->join('users', 'links.user_id = users.id');
    $this->db->join('link_ratings', 'links.id = link_ratings.link_id','left');      

    $get_latest = $this->db->get();

    return $get_latest;

}
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
function get_latest(){
    $this->db->select('list.*, users.*, links.id as current_link_id');
    $this->db->from('links');
    $this->db->join('list', 'links.list_id = list.id'); 
    $this->db->join('users', 'links.user_id = users.id');
    $this->db->join('link_ratings', 'links.id = link_ratings.link_id','left');      
    $this->db->order_by('links.date_created', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit(100);
    $get_latest = $this->db->get()->result_array(); #fetch all rows here
    echo "<pre>";print_r( $get_latest );die; #print all rows and see if its fetching ratings corrctly or not.
    echo $this->db->last_query();die; #check the query generated
    return $get_latest;
}
```

Comment: I maybe wasn't clear. I am retrieving data but it is the `rating` column within the `links` table which is causing me problems. Foreach time I loop through in my view it simply shows 0 for the `rating` index rather than the numbers which are in the database for that specific row. My joins are the problem.

Comment: Any ideas on how I should construct my `joins`?

Comment: Have you seen the resultant array structure you are getting? see above  and try it once.

Comment: Yes I've already had a look and it shows all the correct keys/columns but link `rating` values are all set to `0`. Any suggestions on what join queries may work?

Comment: Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

The reason will be purely logical, in that the join will be causing no results to be returned because there *are no* results. I've fallen into this many times.

I am not able to diagnose your particular problem but when faced with issues like this I:

1- turn on the CI profiler

2- var_dump the array so you can see what's going on

3- write a traditional SQL query and run it in PHPMyAdmin

One, or a combination of all three, will enable you to diagnose.